# Groovy syntax - uploading artifacts

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, jenkins-groovy

For uploading artifacts, with given `uploadSpec`,

1)
Below code

`server.upload(uploadSpec)`

**does not upload** the artifacts

2)
Below code

`server.upload spec: uploadSpec`

**upload** the artifacts

---

From syntax perspective, I can understand the first case, where `uploadSpec` is passed as argument to `server.upload()` method

How to understand syntax? `server.upload spec: uploadSpec, failNoOp: true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second syntax is the equivalent of: `server.upload([spec: uploadSpec])`.  That is call `upload` on `server` and pass a map.  The map has a single key `"spec"` and its value is `uploadSpec`.  For your third example, its still a map, but with two keys (`"spec"` and `"failNoOp"`)

Comment: Does server.upload() internally use jfrog cli?

Comment: I don't know.  This is just explaining what is going on in groovy.

Comment: So, what exactly is the term to refer such syntax, in second case? In the first case, it is a method(`upload`) call expression. How do I term this syntax in second case?

Comment: How to write `server.upload spec: uploadSpec, failNoOp: true` with first syntax?

Comment: My answer states, what your shorthand implies.  It's still a method call.  And it takes one argument and the argument is a Map.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is 'Java' syntax, while the two other are 'Groovy' syntax.
Both are acceptable.

The upload method accepts three inputs:

1. spec - mandatory.
2. buildInfo - optional. default: null.
3. failNoOp - optional. default: false.

In any of the two syntaxes, you must provide spec, and may provide any of the other two options. If you choose to not provide, the default values are used.

You can see this directly from [code](https://github.com/jfrog/jenkins-artifactory-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfrog/hudson/pipeline/common/types/ArtifactoryServer.java#L128).

More info can be found in the [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins#WorkingWithPipelineJobsinJenkins-UploadingandDownloadingFiles.1).